# getJSONObject with an Array

Tags: java, php, android, json, listview

i am trying to work with android and php json , i try to get  something like this , how it is shown in an example.

the example json respone is: { "android": [ { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" }, { "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4" }]}

and my json respone is: 
[{"post_id":"3","user_id":"1","post_inhalt":"lolli","likes":"1"},{"post_id":"4","user_id":"1","post_inhalt":"lala","likes":"2"}]

ther is my problem, i want one object with an array;

my php code looks like this.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
//echo "Welcome, I am connecting Android to PHP, MySQL";

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$user_id = "1";
//Für die Überprüfung
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM post where user_id='$user_id'");

$response = array(); 

// fetch data in array format  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 

    //$response["code"] = 1;
    // Fetch data of Fname Column and store in array of row_array  
    /*
    $row_array["post"]['post_id'] = $row['post_id'];  
    $row_array["post"]['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
    $row_array["post"]['post_inhalt'] = $row['post_inhalt']; 
    $row_array["post"]['likes'] = $row['likes']; 
    */

    $row_array['post_id'] = $row['post_id'];  
    $row_array['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
    $row_array['post_inhalt'] = $row['post_inhalt']; 
    $row_array['likes'] = $row['likes']; 


    //push the values in the array  
    array_push($response,$row_array);   

    }


print json_encode($response);



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i want to put this in my android list view, but everytime i run my app , the error : 
'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

because of that i think the data cant be found from my android. i am not the best in android, so maybe some one can help me.

here is my update of my php code:

```
//while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {



    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //$response["code"] = 1;
    // Fetch data of Fname Column and store in array of row_array  

    /*
    $row_array["post"]['post_id'] = $row['post_id'];  
    $row_array["post"]['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
    $row_array["post"]['post_inhalt'] = $row['post_inhalt']; 
    $row_array["post"]['likes'] = $row['likes']; 
    */
    //$row_array = array();

    $row_array['post_id'] = $row['post_id'];  
    $row_array['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
    $row_array['post_inhalt'] = $row['post_inhalt']; 
    $row_array['likes'] = $row['likes']; 

    //Funktioniert auch, gib aber nur ein array zurück
    //$response[] = $row;

    $response["post"] = array();
    //push the values in the array  
    array_push($response["post"],$row_array);   

}


print json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Hard to tell... it'sin the code where you are getting the jsonarray... you can use optSJSONArray instead of getJSONArray... always use opt... instead of get... did you try getJSONArray("android");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the row array to your resporse like this:

`$respone["android"][$i] = $row_array;`

ofcouse `$i` is the place in the array

Something like this:

```
$response["android"] = array(); 
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 

    $row_array['post_id'] = $row['post_id'];  
    $row_array['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
    $row_array['post_inhalt'] = $row['post_inhalt']; 
    $row_array['likes'] = $row['likes']; 

    $response["android"][$i] = $row_array;  
}
```

Comment: ok i have changed my php code a little bit , see it above, now i have one json object wich contains an array, but just only one array: how can i change this ?